# Exporting custom fields with Squash TM

Tags: export

I am currently using Squash Test Management (http://www.squashtest.org/) for a project. We have a few hundred test cases that now need to be exported from Squash and imported into another test management tool.

The problem is that we have created custom fields (boolean 'automated test') in Squash that is not included in the export file (Excel/CSV).

Squash version in use 1.4.

I did not find information about exporting custom fields in more recent versions. Is this possible? Current version is 1.9.

Is there another practical way to extract this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying the online demo of Squash TM v1.10.2.RELEASE (https://demo.squashtest.org/) I can answer the question myself:
With that version it is possible to search the tests for custom fields. Then I can export the search results. (Searching for custom fields is not availble in 1.4.)

Comment: In Squash TM 1.9, we added an excel test case import / export feature. You can export custom fields bound to test cases using it